# How can I pass id with URL using PHP header function?

Tags: php

I am facing problem to pass variable as id with php header function. I have given my code here. Assume the variable is $id which has an integer value 2. I want to redirect the page to **example.php?id=2** How can I do that?

This is not working. Need your favor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [php header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

```
<?php
   header('Location: example.php?id='.$id);
   exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine: `header('Location: example.php?id='.$id);`. Make sure there is no output, not even a space, before you call the `header();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the header function like this.

```
header("location:example.php?id=".$id);
```